# Unexpected compiler error in Python program

Tags: python, sum

This problem is from Hackerrank.

Given five positive integers, find the minimum and maximum values that can be calculated by summing exactly four of the five integers. Then print the respective minimum and maximum values as a single line of two space-separated long integers.

Test case: `arr = [1,3,5,7,9]` `Output: 16 24`

This seems a trivial problem and my code is:

```
def miniMaxSum(arr):
    arr.sort()
    return sum(arr[0:4])," ",sum(arr[1:5])
```

It gives a `Compiler Message Wrong Answer` error. What is the obvious thing I'm missing out on?

Comment: The return value should be `(16, ' ', 24)`, not what you expect.

Comment: Are you supposed to return that space?

Comment: You should probably be returning a string, not a tuple. And it wants you to print it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could try this:

```
def miniMaxSum(arr):
    arr.sort()
    print(sum(arr[0:4]), sum(arr[1:]))  # 5 is out of index
```

since it does ask that vals be printed.
Simply having a comma between values will place a space between the values.

If you return values from a func they will return as a tuple, and you would print them like this:

```
vals = miniMaxSum(arr)
print(vals[0], vals[1])
```